# For loop and too much loops is making the execution time very longer?

Tags: php, performance, symfony, processing-efficiency

I am currently facing a nightmare. My DB has only **400 Records** almost and the problem is that my PHP code which is generating Image Sliders so the code is taking like **60 Seconds** almost to get executed for only **400 Records** which is way too much time, No one can bear to wait for that much time. 
I am really worried about it as I am not sure what could be done which could make it faster but so far to my knowledge is that by using foreach loop instead of for loop can make things faster but I want to know if you people can please provide me with solutions.

It's a Partial Template inside a Symfony Site which renders the Image Slider and fetching slider each image from the DB. But I am not worried about the SQL Queries as that only takes about **3 to 4 seconds** at most to execute all queries to get these slider images but this code which generates the slider takes like a hell of a lot more time almost **60+ Seconds** in most cases which is too much time for anyone to wait around.

If you people can provide me with optimized code for best performance, I would be grateful for that.

Here the stats as : 
[image]

[image]
Here is my code as **(_searchResults.php)** :

```
<?php if (count($locations) > 0): ?>
  <?php foreach ($locations as $location): ?>
    <?php if ($location->PhotoFiles->count()): ?>
      <li class="item" data-location-id="<?php echo $location->id ?>">
        <div class="searchItemSlider">
          <?php $limit = ($location->PhotoFiles->count() >= 10 ? 10 : $location->PhotoFiles->count()); ?>
          <?php for ($i = 1; $i < ($limit + 1); $i++): ?>
            <?php $photo = $location->findPhotoIndex($i); ?>
            <?php //if (1): ?>
            <?php  if ($photo && $thumb = $photo->getThumbnailByType(ThumbnailTable::THUMB_520_392)): ?>
              <div class="searchItem">
                <figure>
                  <?php  if (file_exists($thumb->getFullFilesystemPath())): ?>
                    <?php //if (1 == 2): ?>
                    <div class="thumb-img">
                      <img class="lazyOwl" src="<?php echo $thumb->getFullWebPath() ?>" />
                    </div>
                  <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="thumb-img">
                      <img class="lazyOwl" src="/images/newfrontend/categories/no_venue.jpg" />
                    </div>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <figcaption>
                    <a href="<?= url_for("@venue_details?id=" . $location->id) ?>" title="<?php echo $location->venue_name; ?>"><?php echo $location->venue_name; ?></a>
                    <br />
                  </figcaption>
                  <?php $districtName = (strlen($location->venue_area)) ? $location->venue_area : $location->getGeoLocationDistrictName();
                    if (strlen($districtName)): ?>
                    <div class="district_name"><a href="<?= url_for("@venue_details?id=" . $location->id) ?>" title="<?php echo $location->venue_name; ?>"><?php echo $districtName ?></a></div>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </figure>
                <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($location->description)), 0, 100) ?></p>
                <span class="eye"><a href="<?= url_for("@venue_details?id=" . $location->id) ?>" title="<?php echo $location->venue_name; ?>"><img src="/images/newfrontend/icons/eye-icon.png"/></a></span>

                <div class="links">                  
                  <a href="<?php echo url_for('@venue_share?id=' . $location->id) ?>" class="arrow share_links" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share this venue">&nbsp;</a>
                  <?php if (!$sf_user->locationInWishlist($location->id)): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo url_for('@wishlist_addtowishlistajaxraw') ?>" data-attr-venue-id="<?php echo $location->id ?>" class="pin add_to_wishlist" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to wishlist">&nbsp;</a>
                  <?php else: ?>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="added-to-wishlist">&nbsp;</a>
          <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endfor; ?>
        </div>
      </li>
    <?php else: ?>
      <li class="item" data-location-id="<?php echo $location->id ?>">
        <div class="searchItemSlider">
          <div class="searchItem">
            <figure>
              <div class="thumb-img">
                <img class="lazyOwl" src="/images/newfrontend/categories/no_venue.jpg" />
              </div>
              <figcaption>
                <a href="<?= url_for("@venue_details?id=" . $location->id) ?>" title="<?php echo $location->venue_name; ?>"><?php echo $location->venue_name; ?></a>
                <br />
              </figcaption>
              <?php $districtName = (strlen($location->venue_area)) ? $location->venue_area : $location->getGeoLocationDistrictName();

              if (strlen($districtName)):
                ?>
              <div class="district_name"><a href="<?= url_for("@venue_details?id=" . $location->id) ?>" title="<?php echo $location->venue_name; ?>"><?php echo $districtName ?></a></div>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </figure>
            <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($location->description)), 0, 100) ?></p>
            <span class="eye"><a href="<?= url_for("@venue_details?id=" . $location->id) ?>" title="<?php echo $location->venue_name; ?>"><img src="/images/newfrontend/icons/eye-icon.png"/></a></span>

            <div class="links">                  
              <a href="<?php echo url_for('@venue_share?id=' . $location->id) ?>" class="arrow share_links" title="Share this venue">&nbsp;</a>
              <?php if (!$sf_user->locationInWishlist($location->id)): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo url_for('@wishlist_addtowishlistajaxraw') ?>" data-attr-venue-id="<?php echo $location->id ?>" class="pin add_to_wishlist" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to wishlist">&nbsp;</a>
              <?php else: ?>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="added-to-wishlist">&nbsp;</a>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Update :**

**Location :** /lib/model/doctrine/PhotoFile.class.php

```
  /**
   * Returns the first thumbnail of a certain type
   * or false if no thumbnail matches
   *
   * @param const $type The type of thumbnail, from the ThumbnailTable::THUMB_* constants
   * @return bool|Thumbnail
   */
  public function getThumbnailByType($type) {
    foreach ($this->Thumbnails as $t) {
      if ($t->thumb_type == $type) {
        return $t;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

**Location :** /lib/model/doctrine/Location.class.php

```
   /**
   * Geocoder: get district name (administrative county)
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getDistrictName()
  {
    return ($this->hasGeocode() ? $this->getGeocode()->district_name : null);
  }

  public function getGeoLocationDistrictName()
  {
    $districtName = '';
    if($this->getGeocoded()->count() > 0)
    {
      if($this->getGeocoded()->getFirst()->getGeolocationPostcode()->count() > 0)
      {
        if($this->getGeocoded()->getFirst()->getGeolocationPostcode()->getFirst()->getGeolocationDistrict()->count() > 0)
        {
          $districtName = $this->getGeocoded()->getFirst()->getGeolocationPostcode()->getFirst()->getGeolocationDistrict()->getFirst()->getName();
        }
      }
    }
    return $districtName;
  }

 /**
   * Gets the geocode data for this location.
   * We store it locally so we don't need to keep querying for it.
   *
   * @return boolean|PcawCodes $pcawCode
   */
  public function getGeocode()
  {
    if ($this->Geocoded->count())
    {
      return $this->Geocoded->getFirst();
    }

    if (!strlen($this->address_postcode))
    {
      // No postcode to geocode
      return false;
    }

    $geocode = new JointGeocoder();
    try
    {
      /* @var $result PcawCodes */
      $result = $geocode->geocode("", $this->address_postcode);

      // Add the postcode also to the GeolocationPostcode table
      if($result) Doctrine::getTable('GeolocationPostcode')->addPostcodeIfMissing($result);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      // Some problem occurred geocoding, return false
      return false;
    }

    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: How do you know, did you benchmark your code to see where it's spending it's time?

Comment: `only takes about 3 to 4 seconds at most to execute all queries`  The average persons attention span is about 6 seconds, I try to have a page load under that.

Comment: you can also avoid same calculation again and again, like `$location->PhotoFiles->count()` is used 3 times, you can store that in one variable and use it

Comment: You can borrow my benchmark class from my `Evolution` framework I am writing ( yes I'm writing my own framework, shameless plug ) here https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/Evo/Benchmark.php

Comment: you use it like this, `$mark = Benchmark::getInstance()->mark('A'); ..other code ... echo Benchmark::getInstance()->format($mark);` and it will say how long it took between start and end.

Comment: Why do people write php in a html document instead of the other way around? Meaning keep the php tag open and echo the few html tags. Is there a real purpose of writing this way?

Comment: @Andreas - it's all about the quoting.  Personally I use template systems for html ( ps, I'm writing one of those too )

Comment: Do you really need to render 389 results? Also, retrieve information in the controller, do nothing but interpolate results

Comment: whats this `getThumbnailByType()` a database call or are you resizing the images, or pulling it from a file.  Image processing in real time on that many elements, yea that's not gonna work out to good.

Comment: i think you should limit your image slider default number of images like 10. You just need to roll the other images once user will traverse the images till the 7th/8th, then you will request for the next batch thru ajax.

Comment: is this an external HTTP request `getGeoLocationDistrictName` etc, see you need to bench mark this and see what is eating you time up.

Comment: So ugly with PHP and HTML mixed, when I get my template system done you can use it ... lol ... it's a  Parser/Lexer.  It will be sweet.  Much prettier then this

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I am just using the Symfony builtin Web Debug Toolbar and it stats all those times for each action.

Answer (score 2):

I note that the benchmarking tool you're using seems to indicate the page is making 4540 queries. If so that is probably the cause.

Based on your code I suspect this is the n+1 problem - essentially making another query inside a loop by fetching a new model individually. Most ORMs have a mechanism to solve that via eager loading, whereby they fetch all of those rows beforehand. Using eager loading also makes it easier to cache the response.

I'm not familiar with Doctrine, but according to https://tideways.io/profiler/blog/5-doctrine-orm-performance-traps-you-should-avoid it supports eager loading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to specifically tell you how you can fix this problem, but instead make suggestions for improving performance.

1. 3 - 4 seconds for your queries to complete is a LONG time. Optimise your database schema, analyse queries, use appropriate indexes.
2. Only query the data that you need. If you don't need 400 results, limit your query appropriately.
3. How often does this data really change? Does it always need to be up-to-date? Parse the data into the structure you need in your controller or a service class and then cache that to a file or similar.
4. Read the cached data, rather than hitting the database every time.
5. Do not generate thumbnails on the fly or at time of need. Generate them when uploading, or generate them once and cache them for future use.
6. Build your view and cache your view, so that you're again not hitting the database every time.
7. Serve your content with appropriate cache headers so the page and/or assets are cached by the user's browser.